# iFrame not Loading some URL's but loading others

Tags: html, iframe

So, I'm confused pretty severely... So I went to w3Schools iFrame page. Copy and pasted this code into codepen directly from w3schools...

`<iframe src="https://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>`

I also tried changing the URL a few times. Loading Google even didn't work... All that happens is a blank page with the same background color as the parent page. I dont understand why the iframe code even from w3schools doesn't work... Am i not loading a dependency? I'm using the latest version of chrome.

index.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Soundcloud Downloader</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <iframe src="http://1stdibs.com/"></iframe>
        <iframe src="http://soundtake.net/"></iframe>
        <iframe src="https://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

A working code pen:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GEePEK

My view (screenshot):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBH03.jpg

Comment: Maybe it`s http vs https? Check out errors in dev console in your browser.

Comment: Google is definitely one of those sites that sends "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN" response header. That requires that the parent must be running on the same domain as the child page inside the iframe. So unless you own google.com it aint gonna happen.

Answer (score 2):

Check this one
[Checking if a website doesn't permit iframe embed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422300/checking-if-a-website-doesnt-permit-iframe-embed) and this one too [Certain websites won't appear with Iframe and .load() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33305732/certain-websites-wont-appear-with-iframe-and-load-function).
I had same problem few year back then i came through these,some sites avoid iframe tag.